# problem with Importing multiple files

Tags: import, list-manipulation

I need to import about 100000 "dat" files to my progrom. I want to do this using the last answer to this question:

[Importing multiple files using a for-loop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22357/importing-multiple-files-using-a-for-loop/22358#22358)

I know that I should define a list of all the names of my files, and at the end, I `Import` all of them. But I have a problem with this. The names of my files obey a special pattern, like this:

```
"mutomu,dms41,x1,dms51,x2,q24,x3,q25,x4.dat"
```

Which x1-x4 are integers in this way:

```
{x1, 1, 21}, {x2, x1, 21}, {x3, 1, 15}, {x4, 1, 15}
```

. When I am defining the names of my files, I do it as:

```
allprobabilityfiles = {Flatten[Table[{{x1, x2, x3, x4},"mutomu,dms41,x1,dms51,x2,q24,x3,q25,x4.dat"}, {x1, 1, 21,1}, {x2, x1, 21, 1}, {x3, 1, 15, 1}, {x4, 1, 15, 1}], 3]};
```

but in this way, the result is:

```
....{{21, 21, 6, 5}, "mutomu,dms41,x1,dms51,x2,q24,x3,q25,x4.dat"}, 
{{21, 21, 6, 6}, "mutomu,dms41,x1,dms51,x2,q24,x3,q25,x4.dat"}, 
{{21, 21, 6, 7}, "mutomu,dms41,x1,dms51,x2,q24,x3,q25,x4.dat"}, ....
```

(x1-x4 don't change inside the file names in this table), but what I need is the following:

```
....{{21, 21, 6, 5}, "mutomu,dms41,21,dms51,21,q24,6,q25,5.dat"}, 
{{21, 21, 6, 6}, "mutomu,dms41,21,dms51,21,q24,5,q25,6.dat"}, 
{{21, 21, 6, 7}, "mutomu,dms41,21,dms51,21,q24,5,q25,7.dat"}, ....
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can also refer to [this solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14741/1871) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringForm` is useful for embedding values into a control string:

```
filestring[vals__] := 
 ToString @ StringForm["mutomu,dms41,``,dms51,``,q24,``,q25,``.dat", vals]

filestring[10, 20, 30, 40]
(*  "mutomu,dms41,10,dms51,20,q24,30,q25,40.dat"  *)
```

You would just drop this function into your `Table` like so:

```
allprobabilityfiles = 
  Flatten[Table[{{x1, x2, x3, x4}, filestring[x1, x2, x3, x4]}, 
   {x1, 1, 21, 1}, {x2, x1, 21, 1}, {x3, 1, 15, 1}, {x4, 1, 15, 1}], 3];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I liked it :)...

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
Table[{x1, "mutomu," <> ToString[x1] <> ",dms51.dat"}, {x1, 
  Range@4}]
```

(* 
{{1, "mutomu,1,dms51.dat"}, {2, "mutomu,2,dms51.dat"}, {3, 
  "mutomu,3,dms51.dat"}, {4, "mutomu,4,dms51.dat"}}
*)

It is very easy to implement in your cases.

Edit:

Ok, I'll fit the code above for your case:

```
allprobabilityfiles = 
  Flatten[Table[{{x1, x2, x3, x4}, 
     "mutomu,dms41," <> ToString[x1] <> ",dms51," <> ToString[x2] <> 
      ",q24," <> ToString[x3] <> ",q25," <> ToString[x4] <> 
      ".dat"}, {x1, 1, 21, 1}, {x2, 1, 21, 1}, {x3, 1, 15, 1}, {x4, 1,
      15, 1}], 3];
allprobabilityfiles[[1 ;; 5]]
```

(*
{{{1, 1, 1, 1}, 
  "mutomu,dms41,1,dms51,1,q24,1,q25,1.dat"}, {{1, 1, 1, 2}, 
  "mutomu,dms41,1,dms51,1,q24,1,q25,2.dat"}, {{1, 1, 1, 3}, 
  "mutomu,dms41,1,dms51,1,q24,1,q25,3.dat"}, {{1, 1, 1, 4}, 
  "mutomu,dms41,1,dms51,1,q24,1,q25,4.dat"}, {{1, 1, 1, 5}, 
  "mutomu,dms41,1,dms51,1,q24,1,q25,5.dat"}}
*)

More elegantly:

```
fileName := {{##}, 
    "mutomu,dms41," <> ToString[#1] <> ",dms51," <> ToString[#2] <> 
     ",q24," <> ToString[#3] <> ",q25," <> ToString[#4] <> ".dat"} &;
Flatten[Array[fileName, {21, 21, 15, 15}], 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't what I am looking for. `"mutomu,dms41,21,dms51,21,q24,6,q25,5.dat"` (for example) is the name of my file, and at the end I should have something like that!

Comment: Thanks again. I just have one other question. I can see that `<>` must be available before and after `ToString` to put everything in the correct form. However, what is `<>` really doing?

Comment: StringJoin. I think you can type ?<> in Mathematica to get the information.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `FileNames` to select the files you want to import.

```
data=Import/@FileNames["/mydirpath/mutomu*dat"];
```

Or it may prove easier to move the data files to their own directory where you can use:

```
data=Import/@FileNames["/mydatadirpath/*"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew this way, but I was avoiding to use it. I need to do it exactly as yulinlinyu's answer.

Comment: I like this answer.

Comment: @Zahra Thank you, I'm glad you found the right solution to your problem :)