# Importing colors from file

Tags: import, color

I just tried something straightforward (for me):

```
dummy = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=g8D7NprC", "List"] & /@ col;
colors = dummy[[1]];
ToExpression@colors;
Graphics[{colors, Rectangle[{0, 0}]}]
```

Is it not possible to import color data from a file?

Comment: it works fine if you remove `& /@ col` at the end of the first line.

Comment: Ok I don't know much but now there is nothing happening. No output at all. Which is very weird when it works fine with you. It states "RGBColor[0, 0, 1] is not a Graphics primitive or directive"

Comment: I think it is because your `colors` is a string; to change it to a color directive use `ToExpression@colors`...

Comment: Or just `color = << "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GXbeGrcD"`.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work for many lines of text with different colors? I need to address different colors through colors[[i]] @kguler : Is that above what you meant? It does not work either.

Comment: @user3683367 - you oversimplified your question. what does your file to be imported REALLY look like? does it contain DIFFERENT colors, a list of colors ? But even in this case: How, exactly, do you want to color ONE rectangle with these different colors?

Comment: I edited the file so it contains more than one argument. I can have it look like I want so this way is not fixed. And one rectangle one color.

Comment: @user3683367, you need use `colors = ToExpression@colors`; or `colors=Toexpression[dummy[[1]]]`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like the following:

```
 dummy = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=g8D7NprC", "List"];
 colors = ToExpression /@ dummy;
 Graphics[Thread[{colors, Rectangle/@ RandomInteger[10, {5, 2}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted. Would you recommend using "Thread" or "Sequence" like in the following question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48818/animation-of-moving-rectangles-in-2d-from-data-file

Comment: @user3683367, you probably will be using this in an animation similar to the linked question; so i would recommend using the same setup... that is, `{colors[[t]],Rectangle @@ (rectCoords[[t]])}` with `t` the index you use in `Animate` or `Table`...