# Importing multiple files with a loop

Tags: import, data

I have 101 files with data that I want to import into Mathematica. All the file names are numbered as follows datafile.20.0000.out, datafile.20.1000.out, datafile.20.2000.out and so on. I used the solution posted here [Importing multiple files using a for-loop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22357/importing-multiple-files-using-a-for-loop)

However, the problem I am facing is the zeros at the end. I tried using

```
z = Table[i, {i, 20, 30, 0.1}]

Data = 
  Table[
    Import["C:\\Dropbox\\Sims\\datafile." <> 
      ToString[NumberForm[z[[j]], {6, 4}]] <> ".out", "Data"], 
    {j, 20, 30, 0.1}]
```

But I'm getting error messages.

I would like to retrieve date of each file by `Data[[20]]`, `Data[[20.1]]` and so on.

Comment: what is the first file name? is it `datafile.20.0000.out`? so what is the last file full name? is it `datafile.20.1010.out` ? You can't have an index that is not discrete. So index 20.1 will not work.

Comment: Just for starters, `Data[[20.1]]` is invalid syntax, list indices must be integers.

Comment: Yes, the first one is datafile.20.0000 and the last one is datafile.30.0000. Yeah I made a mistake with the index. I suppose Data[[1]], Data[[2]] and so on storing datafile.20.0000, datafile.20.1000 and so on respectively.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little integer and string hacking generates all and only the names required.

```
Data = Table[s = ToString[j]; 
  Import["C:\\Dropbox\\Sims\\datafile." <> StringTake[s, 2] <> "." <> 
  StringDrop[s, 2] <> ".out", "Data"], {j, 200000, 300000, 1000}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use **FileNames** to get list of *.out* files

```
data = Import[#, "Data"] &/@ FileNames["datafile.*.out", "C:\\Dropbox\\Sims\\", 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
data= Import["c:\\dropbox\\sims\\datafile.20." 
<> IntegerString[#, 10, 4] <> ".out" ]& /@ Range[1000]
```