# Replace a number in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I have several data files I want to import. The names of these files consist of a part that is the same for all of them and a number which identifies them, as in `"restofname-NUMBER"`. I tried to make a list `list` of the numbers in question and then to import by

```
Import["restofname-" <> # & /@ StringForm[list], "Table"],
```

but that leaves me with the error

> String expected at position 1 in StringForm[1]

I'm guessing `StringForm` is not what I need, but have no idea what else to use.

Comment: try `ToString` .

Comment: Argh, what a mess of brackets I made. Deleted the previous comment. This seems to work properly: `(data[#] = Import["restofname-" <> ToString[#], "Table"]) & /@ list`

Comment: Also check [`IntegerString[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html) in case you need padding, e.g. *name-001.dat*

Comment: Concerning "what else to use": `?*String*` can be worth a try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61652/importing-multiple-files-with-a-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way of doing it, so the following is not exactly an answer to the question. Here is how I would do it assuming that I have padding.

### 0 Preparation

```
data={1,2,3};(*some test data*)
(*exporting to some files*)
Table[Export["myData" <> IntegerString[i, 10, 5] <> ".txt", data], {i,10}];
(*and deleting one to make it a bit more complicated*)
DeleteFile["myData00003.txt"];
```

Now how to proceed? Check the files.

```
FileNames[]
```

> {"desktop.ini","Ma musique", "Mes images","Mes vidéos","myData00001.txt",
>   "myData00002.txt", "myData00004.txt", "myData00005.txt", "myData00006.txt", "myData00007.txt", "myData00008.txt", "myData00009.txt", "myData00010.txt", "test.xls"}

```
(*Now let us take only the ones that start with the right name*)
fList = Select[FileNames[], (StringMatchQ[#, StartOfString ~~ "myData" ~~ __] &)];
(*or directly using the power of FileNames[]*)
fList = FileNames["myData*"]
```

> {"myData00001.txt", "myData00002.txt", "myData00004.txt", \
>   "myData00005.txt", "myData00006.txt", "myData00007.txt", \
>   "myData00008.txt", "myData00009.txt", "myData00010.txt"}

```
(*If we want the numbers of those we can use regular expressions*)
(*If the lengths are all fixed, StringDrop[] can also work*)
numbers=ToExpression[Flatten[StringCases[#, RegularExpression["[0-9]+"]] & /@ fList]]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

So there are two ways now:

### 1a Knowing the numbers

If we know that it starts at `1` and ends at `10` with `3` missing, we just do:

```
Table[If[i != 3, iData[i] = Import["myData" <> IntegerString[i, 10, 5]<> ".txt","Table"]], {i, 10}];
```

### 1b Using the file list

If we are not sure about the numbers we use the file list and extract the numbers from the file names:

```
Table[ 
    newiData[   
        ToExpression[     
            StringCases[i, RegularExpression["[0-9]+"] 
            ]
        ][[1]]
    ] = Import[i, "Table"], {i, fList}]
```

### Remarks

Now `iData[i]` and `newiData[i]` should be identical.

Note that especially the second case works if you have file names of the type:

```
"known name"<>"variational unknown part"<>"unknown length numbers"<>".dat"
```