# Importing multiple files

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I am looking to import multiple .txt files. So far I have been importing them individually like this:

```
file1 = Import["C:\\file1.txt", "Table"];
```

I'd like to be able to do `files[1]`, `files[2]`, etc., instead of assigning individual file names to each import.

I tried doing the method described in the top answer of this post:
[Importing multiple files using a for-loop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22357/importing-multiple-files-using-a-for-loop)

But typing the following, I get "file not found during input"

```
testlist = 
  Table[
    Import[
      "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb\\Climb 90000 0.78.txt" <> 
        ToString[i] <> ".txt,", 
      "Data"], 
    {i, 4}]
```

---

```
 FileNames["*.txt", "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb"]
```

> ```
> {"C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb\\Climb 100000 0.78.txt", 
>  "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb\\Climb 100000 240.txt", 
>  "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb\\Climb 100000 300.txt", 
>  "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb\\Climb 90000 0.78.txt", 
>  "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb\\Climb 90000 240.txt", 
>  "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb\\Climb 90000 300.txt"}
> ```

Comment: Can you talk about what your scheme for the filenames is?

Comment: Are your files really named `0.78.txt.123.txt` for `i=123`?

Comment: the files are named like Climb 90000 0.78.txt It works for the first method I am using. Should I change the file names?

Comment: Change the `Table[` so it returns the list of filenames instead of calling `Import`. Then change the string expression until it returns the right file names.

Comment: That is still a bit vague. Please evaluate `FileNames["*.txt", "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb"]` and paste in the results of that in your question.

Comment: It looks like you can just do `Import[#, "Data"] & /@ FileNames["*.txt", "C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb"]`, then.

Comment: ok that works but then how do I take the data from a specific file and process it. For example, I took each file and did the following because the file consists of mulitple columns of data  `table1a = Cases[climb90078, {_, _, _, _, __}];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get all the file names and then import them.

```
allFiles = FileNames["*.txt","C:\\Users\\joep\\Documents\\Scenario 2\\Climb"];
allData = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ allFiles
```

Now you can access the individual data pieces by indexing into allData, for instance:

```
allData[[n]]
```

gets the nth set.

Comment: This worked for me thank you very much

Comment: Very helpful...