# How to extract email addresses from a text file using Mathematica

Tags: import, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, email

I have a text file which I have uploaded [here](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/data.txt). I want to find all email addresses in this text file. I just know that some of them are after "Subscription Date" expression (I don't know if there is a better way to find all of email addresses in a txt file). I saw several questions like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245918/importing-selected-data-from-text-files) but they don't work for me. Also I tried this

```
res = Import["data.txt", "Lines"];
tar = Position[res, "\"Subscription Date\""][[1, 1]];
```

but this is not the answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = Import[
  "http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/data.txt", 
  "Text"]
```

Benefitting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) discussion (and don't ask me about the pattern):

```
tx = StringCases[data, 
   RegularExpression[
    "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\
)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\
\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]\
*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-\
4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-\
9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\\
x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\\
x7f])+)\\])
"]];

list1 = Union@(StringTrim @tx)
```

This still has multiple email entries and some website strings that have not been filtered.

---

For Mathematica users, a more native (and better) way would be:

```
temail = StringCases[data, 
   Whitespace | StartOfLine ~~ 
    Shortest[("_" | "-" | WordCharacter | ".") ..] ~~ "@" ~~ 
    Shortest[(WordCharacter | ".") ..] ~~ (Whitespace | "," | 
      EndOfLine | "&")];

list2 = Union@(StringTrim @temail);
```

and it is quite readable on its own.

`StringTrim` and `Union`simply do the required cleanup.

---

**For comparison**

```
{Length@list1, Length@list2} (*{652, 785} *)
```

As an exercise, do the following to verify the differences:

```
Complement[list1, list2]; (*25 ?entries due to uppercase etc*)
Complement[list2, list1];
```

---

Comment: Thanks but how this works?! I replace `data` by `res` and get 33788 empty lists!

Comment: Many Thanks, your pattern is very clean, but it doesn't give all emails. Anyway I will be so grateful if you add some explanations to your pattern for clarification.

Comment: For learning about these reserved words, you can press `F1` and try examples in the docs. Experiment with your own file step by step. Please let me know, which emails  this pattern left out?

Comment: I didn't compare, but your pattern gives 428 results while the first one gives 652 after `DeleteDuplicate` command. I know the 652 is close to correct results.

Comment: @Wisdom I have updated the answer.

Comment: Now your pattern became perfect. Great job!

Comment: `list3 = TextCases[data, "EmailAddress"] // DeleteDuplicates;` is also a built-in way of doing all this in Mma, but I will let you explore this further and see the differences yourself. I took the liberty of editing the title/post twice. If you don't like the changes, you can revert them. See you later.

Comment: OMG! such a simple way! Thanks a lot. and feel free to edit everything.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in function `TextCases` gets you most of the way there as it has a built-in `"EmailAddress"` text content type, but it also includes email addresses with some preceding text (like `/my/subscriber?=foo@bar.com`), so we also filter that out with `Select`, and then `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates@
 Select[TextCases[
   Import["http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/data.txt", "String"], 
 "EmailAddress"], Not@StringContainsQ[#, "=" | "/"] &]
```

which returns 777 email addresses.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, Syed introduced this simple way in his last comment