# Batch processing of data files

Tags: programming, export, import

I have a large set of data files containing x-y coordinates.

I have written a notebook to extract angles and other relevant lengths from a single data file before exporting the results into a new data file.

The issues I am facing is that I don't know how to batch process this notebook on the entire data set. What I do now is to manually change the name of the file I am importing before running the notebook and exporting the new data. This is obviously very boring and time consuming.

Therefore I would like to :

- import all the data files (in the form data_xx.dat, all placed in the same folder)
- For each data file run the notebook and get the resulting data (one column table)
- concatenate all the results in one table and export it

Could you indicate me how to do that? Do I need to create another notebook in which I call the already existing notebook? If yes how so?

Many thanks.

Comment: Some answers are here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22357/1783

Comment: If you want to create a notebook like what you already have, for each data file, then look into using Template Notebooks: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateDocument.html